# Grid View Combo Box Column

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Windows Form.

I have a ComboBox and on it's SelectedIndexChanged, I need to bind values to a GridViewComboBox Column.

Suppose I have bound all the states in the ComboBox, then when a state is selected, I need to bind all the districts coming under the particular state.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does a state have a districts collection?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the question truly. Somewhere you wrote Combobox and sometimes GridViewComboBox. Still if you want what I am thinking:

```
datagridview dg;
string[] district = { "dis1", "dis2", "dis3" };
for (int i = 0; i < dg.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cc = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dg["dgc", i];
    cc.DataSource = country;
    cc.Value = country[0];
}
```

dgc = Column name of DatagridViewComboboxColumn.

Here, putting the following code in State Combobox TextChanged event. String array district are district source. Tweak this concept according to your need, I think you will get what you are looking for.
Need any more clarity, add a comment.
Hope it helps.